# Как убрать выделение у svg картинки при наведении

Tags: css

При наведении на эту svg картинку она загорается, но почему у неё появляется квадратный фон, как его убрать?

```
<svg width="52" height="44" viewBox="0 0 52 44" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.09483.......... fill="#0C0C0D" stroke="#D8A65D" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скиньте код svg

Comment: <svg width="52" height="44" viewBox="0 0 52 44" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

Comment: в сам пост. весь код, а не одну строку

Comment: пробовали в `fill` поставить `transparent`?

Comment: потому что у тя тень...

Comment: В svg нет теней... Создай аналогичную фигуру `сердца` и заблюр ее... Будет имитация тени...  Хотя я могу только догадываться, что именно ты хочешь реализовать в итоге...  Еще попробуй `filter: drop-shadow()`